# Android Carousel effect with layouts

Tags: android, layout, view, carousel

I have found lots of carousel examples with images. But i don't find example that works with layout. Can anyone suggest any link with android carousel effect with different layouts.

e.g.  Carousel with listviews. (Each view in the carousel ll be a listview)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you found anything on this?

Comment: can you share link, if found anything??

Answer (score 1):

Here is the project you can [download from this link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mP_AlvJqSLQ)

Its a video which will guide you in right direction ... also there is link to download source code there,, in ShowMore section

Hope this helps..